# how to divide each column in a df by other columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to divide every column in a data frame by each column

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2,3), (2, 4,6), (3, 6,9), (4, 8,12), (5, 10,15)], ["A", "B","C"])
```

So:

- columns A should be divided by B and C
- column B should be divided by A and C
- column C should be divided by A and B

The columns name should be `A_by_B`, `A_by_C` etc.

I can do this in python the following way but not sure how this would work in pyspark

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference([col])].div(df[col], axis=0)\
.add_suffix(f'_by_{col}') for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the DataFrame columns to create the new columns `X_by_Y` like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2,3), (2, 4,6), (3, 6,9), (4, 8,12), (5, 10,15)], ["A", "B","C"])

select_expr = list()
for c in df.columns:
    for denominator in df.columns:
        if c != denominator:
            select_expr.append((col(c)/col(denominator)).alias(f'{c}_by_{denominator}'))

df.select(*select_expr).show()

+------+------------------+------+------------------+------+------+
|A_by_B|            A_by_C|B_by_A|            B_by_C|C_by_A|C_by_B|
+------+------------------+------+------------------+------+------+
|   0.5|0.3333333333333333|   2.0|0.6666666666666666|   3.0|   1.5|
|   0.5|0.3333333333333333|   2.0|0.6666666666666666|   3.0|   1.5|
|   0.5|0.3333333333333333|   2.0|0.6666666666666666|   3.0|   1.5|
|   0.5|0.3333333333333333|   2.0|0.6666666666666666|   3.0|   1.5|
|   0.5|0.3333333333333333|   2.0|0.6666666666666666|   3.0|   1.5|
+------+------------------+------+------------------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 6), (3, 6, 9)], ('A', 'B', 'C'))
df_1 = df.withColumn('A by B', df.A/df.B)
df_2 = df_1.withColumn('A by c', df.A/df.C)
df_3 = df_2.withColumn('B by A', df.B/df.A)
df_4 = df_3.withColumn('B by C', df.B/df.C)
df_4.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this would be very tedious if there are large number of columns.